# Crosstab query does not work in Excel, but works in Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a problem that drives me mad. I have sql query like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Meetings.[ID]) AS [Number of Meetings] 
SELECT Format([Meetings].[Meeting Date], 'Mmm') AS [Meeting Month] 
FROM Meetings 
GROUP BY Month([Meetings].[Meeting Date]), Format([Meetings].[Meeting Date], 'Mmm') 
ORDER BY Month([Meetings].[Meeting Date]), Year(Meetings.[Meeting Date]) 
PIVOT Year(Meetings.[Meeting Date]);
```

It works fine in Access, but when I execute it from Excel I get no records. Opening recordset part is 100% correct, because it works fine with other queries. Does anybody know the reason why it fetches no records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import a crosstab query into Excel from Access you need to jump through some hoops. The crosstab can't be ready by Excel so you should

- make your crosstab query in Access
- create a `Make Table` query that is just `Select * into StaticCrossTab from YourCrossTabQuery`
- go back to Excel and import your data as `Select * from StaticCrossTab`

Kind of a pain but it's the best way I've found to bring cross tab data into Excel from Access. The alternative is to not do the pivot in Access and instead use a pivot table in Excel to create the crosstab you want. Sometimes, depending on the pivot, this is not possible.

Comment: Smart idea! But you're right it's quite painful, and I cannot do this through ADODB connection. I would need Access application object to use CreateQueryDef, right? Today I came up with idea of feeding Excel pivots with query results, and I think I'll go this way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Create the crosstab query in Access (myCrossTabQuery) and then in Excel import using 
  Select * from myCrossTabQuery